# Are exceptions supported in Qt 5?

Tags: c++, qt, exception, build, qt5

In the new version of Qt, it's not possible to pass the command-line parameter -exceptions when configuring. So are exceptions there or not? I use exceptions in my programs a lot. So if exceptions are disabled once and for all... then that's bad news!

Can you guys please explain what happened with exceptions in Qt 5?

Comment: Whether or not Qt is built with or without exceptions doesn't restrict you to the same. Qt uses only few exceptions, but it uses them. So I think compiling with exceptions being enabled is the default, thus there is no such switch. (But I'm not sure with this last point; thus a comment and not an answer.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ability to disable exceptions was originally introduced to deal with pre-standard compilers. Qt has been around a long time.

Today, all compilers supported by Qt support exceptions, so there's no longer a need to disable them.

Comment: @KubaOber: They're called for C++ (synchronous) exceptions, not for SEH (asynchronous) exceptions. But the latter are Undefined Behavior anyway.

Comment: OK, got it, the MSDN documentation isn't clear on that.